# Backbone validation is not executed

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js, coffeescript

it seems that my Coffeescript validation is not taken into account:

```
 class PokerRange extends Backbone.Model
    defaults:
        id:0
        cards:[[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12]]

    validate: (attributes) ->
        if attributes.id<0 then "id should be positive"

window.firstrange= new PokerRange id:5
console.log window.firstrange.toJSON()
window.firstrange.set("id",-4)
console.log window.firstrange.toJSON()
```

This is the result:

```
Object {id: 5, cards: Array[13]}
Object {id: -4, cards: Array[13]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out why, I just forgot to pass as an option to the set method {validate:true}

```
    class PokerRange extends Backbone.Model
    defaults:
        id:0
        cards:[[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12],[0..12]]
    validate: (attributes) ->
        if attributes.id<0 then "id should be positive"

window.firstrange= new PokerRange id:5

window.firstrange.on "invalid", (model, error) ->  alert(error)


console.log window.firstrange.toJSON()
window.firstrange.set {id:-4}, {validate:true}
console.log window.firstrange.toJSON()
```